# Percentage widths don't work in react testing

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, width

Unit testing in react doesn't seem to regard percentage widths. I encountered this problem testing a more complex component and reproduced it in a simpler scenario.
I ran the below tests differently.

```
let div: HTMLElement = null
beforeEach(() => {
   div = document.createElement('div');
   document.body.appendChild(div);
})


//Test 1
it('testing widths', async () => {
        act(() => {
            render(<div id="big" style={{ width: "100px" }}><div id="small" style={{ width: "100%" }}></div></div>, div);
        })

        expect($("#big").width()).toBe(100) //passes
        expect($("#stup").width()).toBe(100) //fails (recieved - 0)
    });


//Test 2
it('testing widths', async () => {
        act(() => {
            render(<div id="big" style={{ width: "100px" }}><div id="small" style={{ width: "100px" }}></div></div>, div);
        })

        expect($("#big").width()).toBe(100) //passes
        expect($("#stup").width()).toBe(100) //passes
    });


//Test 3
it('testing widths', async () => {
        act(() => {
            render(<div id="big" style={{ width: "100px" }}><div id="small"></div></div>, div);
        })

        $("#small").width("100%")
        expect($("#big").width()).toBe(100) //passes
        expect($("#small").width()).toBe(100) //fails (recieved - 0)
    });


//Test 4
it('testing widths', async () => {
        act(() => {
            render(<div id="big" style={{ width: "100px" }}><div id="small"></div></div>, div);
        })

        $("#small").width("100")
        expect($("#big").width()).toBe(100) //passes
        expect($("#small").width()).toBe(100) //passes
    });
```

And for some reason, this fails too (100 instead of 100px)

```
it('testing widths', async () => {
        act(() => {
            render(<div id="big" style={{ width: "100" }}><div id="small" style={{ width: "100" }}></div></div>, div);
        })

        expect($("#big").width()).toBe(100) //fails (recieved - 0)
        expect($("#small").width()).toBe(100) //fails (recieved - 0)
    });
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Percentage *of what*? This is a unit test, there's no viewport.

Comment: Percentage of the outer div of id #big. Since I've set the width of that explicitly to 100px, I expect it's child of width 100% to have the same width. But now that you mention viewport...... You're right. There is indeed no viewport. Seems nothing can be done about this in a test.